# How to get the path of a file but without the actual file name

Tags: java

For example `C:\Desktop` and not `C:\Desktop\file.txt`.
 Here's the  code, what can i do to get only the path excluding the actual name of the file or do i have to mechanically remove the name part(String) with the `split("\")` method.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FilesInfo {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\CCKS\\Desktop\\1");

    public void viewFiles() throws IOException {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        String path = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            if(!files[i].isDirectory()){
                System.out.println("[DIRECTORY]" + files[i].getPath() + " [NAME] " + files[i].toString() + " [SIZE] " + files[i].length() + "KB");
            } else {
                path = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
                file = new File(path);
            }
        }

        if(path.equals("")){
            return;
        } else {
            viewFiles();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){ 
        try {
            new FilesInfo().viewFiles();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this,

```
File file = new File("C:\Desktop\file.txt");
String parentPath= file.getParent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File( "C:/testDir/test1.txt" );
String justPath = file.getParent();
```